# How to give links of different sql tables to datagridview values?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 9)
            {
                SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand("select * from traintime", con);
                DataTable dth = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
                da.Fill(dth);
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dth;
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0 && comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand("select * from traintime where TrainNo=11026", con);
                DataTable dth = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cm1);
                da.Fill(dth);
                dataGridView2.DataSource = dth;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Need some more info, it's not clear what exactly you're asking?

Comment: I mean to say that when i click on datagridview table value 1 then it should redirect to another datagridview table